# Matlab: Creating a binary image with custom values that correspond to "0" and "1"

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary

I have an image. I have found its maximum and minimum pixel values, 0.0165 and -0.6174 respectively, and I was told to create a binary image where the the value "-0.6174" corresponds to "0" and the value "0.0165" corresponds to "1".

I was also told that the intermediate values should be calculated accordingly as well, but I'm not sure how?

Because I thought binary images only have 0 and 1, and no in-between numbers? Could someone clarify this for me please?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be looking to a binary image and only want to nomralize

```
img=(img-min(img(:)))/(max(img(:))-min(img(:)));
```

Will scale your values between 0 and 1, **not** making it binary, but normalized

Comment: I have created a normalised image with your advice, thank you. Now, I wish to create a binary image by corresponding the max value to 1 and the min value to 0, using the mean value as a threshold. Could you help me with this too, please?

Comment: Imgbw=img>mean(img(:));.  Consider accepting the answer as valid @Megan